# AFNetworking not compatible with iOS 4.3

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, afnetworking, cocoapods

I am using CocoaPods to install the AFNetworking library. Here is my simple CocoaPods file:

```
platform :ios
pod 'FMDB'
pod 'AFNetworking'
```

My Pods project and my main project are iOS 6 deployment target and base SDK. When I run the pod install I get the following error:

> ```
> AFNetworking not compatible with iOS 4.3
> ```

UPDATED:

I edited my Podfile to this:

```
platform :ios, '6.0'
pod 'FMDB'
pod 'AFNetworking'
```

Now when I run pod install it shows the following:

Updating spec repo `master'

Cocoapods 0.15.1 is available.

Using AFNetworking (1.0)
Using FMDB (2.0)
Generating support files

But it never adds the AFNetworking pod to the pods project in xCode.

Answer (score 31):

AFNetworking 1.0 and higher requires either iOS 5.0 and above, or Mac OS 10.7 (64-bit with modern Cocoa runtime) and above.

For compatibility with iOS 4.3, use the latest 0.10.x release.

*from:* https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking:

UPDATE, specify iOS dependency in Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '6.0'

pod 'FMDB'
pod 'AFNetworking'
```

UPDATE 2, I create a new project and a new Podfile, run `pod install`:

```
$ pod install
Resolving dependencies of `./Podfile'
Updating spec repositories
Resolving dependencies for target `default' (iOS 6.0)
Downloading dependencies
Installing AFNetworking (1.0)
Installing FMDB (2.0)
Generating support files

[!] From now on use `AF.xcworkspace'.
Integrating `libPods.a' into target `AF' of Xcode project `./AF.xcodeproj'.
```

UPDATE 3,

[image: screen shot]

Comment: I do not need compatibility with iOS 4. My base SDK and deployment target is set to iOS 6 and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: I even deleted the complete pod project and then created a new podfile and still same issue. AFNetworking folder is empty and not being added to the xCode project.

Comment: Screen shot shows AFNetworking files are installed properly: http://i.stack.imgur.com/RCv0l.png It must be something else.

Answer (score 14):

Specifying your Versions of the desired pods may help.

```
platform :ios, '6.0'
pod 'FMDB', '~> 2.0'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 1.1.0'
```

Also make sure you're opening the correct `xcworkspace` file.