# Can I use ASIHTTPRequest in my iphone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Can I use ASIHTTPRequest in my ios App?

Does it still exist?

I am working in ios 4.3. So I cannot use AFNetworking etc.

Comment: ASIHTTPRequest does not support ARC, so you have to specify that. so you have to add  the following compiler flags:

-fno-objc-arc

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966419/afnetworking-not-compatible-with-ios-4-3

Comment: @Nila ASIHTTPRequest,no more support. you can go either for MKNetworkKit or AFNetworking.

Answer (score 3):

ASIHTTPRequest is no more supported. See [Author's blog](http://allseeing-i.com/%5Brequest_release%5D;)

Answer (score 3):

I have developed app using ASIHTTPRequest

Follow the below link to avoid ARC problems.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5677/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-part-1

Answer (score 0):

yes it exists and works fine BUT it isnt actively supported and developed anymore. I wouldnt use that, instead id look at AFNetworking