# How to lock down CocoaPod library version?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoapods

There are currently newer versions of libraries I have specified in my Podfile which break our applications build . It happens when you perform a `pod update`. This is because our Podfile has fuzzy matching versions specified for some of the libraries. We need to lock these down to specific versions , example I have `AFNetworking`, '~> 1.0 in my pod file , When I perform a "pod update" then it install `AFNetworking`', '~> 1.3.3 , but I wanted lock down library to 1.0 only.

Comment: `~> 1.0` will potentially allow updates until `1.9.9`

Answer (score 24):

According to the [podfile syntax reference](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#pod), you can use operators to specify the version of the pod you want to install:

- `> 0.1` Any version higher than 0.1
- `>= 0.1` Version 0.1 and any higher version
- `< 0.1` Any version lower than 0.1
- `<= 0.1` Version 0.1 and any lower version
- `~> 0.1.2` Version 0.1.2 and the versions up to 0.2, not including 0.2

However, in your case it sounds like you want to use just the version number and "freeze" it to 1.0, right? If yes, you can just write

```
pod 'AFNetworking', '1.0'
```

in your podfile.

Note that the `~>` symbol you are using will update up to version 2.0, not including 2.0.

Comment: Will this stop any downloading and replacement of the specified frozen version during pod install and pod update? Or will cocoapods still download a fresh copy of the specified version even though that version is the same ?

Comment: I don't know the internals of CocoaPods, but I guess it wouldn't redownload a dependency that already exists. You can try using the `--verbose` option to see if the logs mention anything interesting though!

Answer (score 7):

When you update your  pod library Try this command;

pod update **--no-repo-update**

or

pod install **--no-repo-update**

so that your current libraries won't be updated.

Here is the link, you can find more details

http://guides.cocoapods.org/terminal/commands.html#pod_update 
http://guides.cocoapods.org/terminal/commands.html#pod_install

Answer (score 3):

You can select needed version in you pod file

```
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 1.0'
```

[Here is similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966419/afnetworking-not-compatible-with-ios-4-3)